# Why is my solution to the k subarray product problem not working?

Tags: c, algorithm, recursion, segmentation-fault, sub-array

I implemented a solution that uses xor to know if a product has been computed before. It recursively gets all the possible products. Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int driver(int *arr, int k, int n){
    int counter=0;
    int sbc=0;
    while(counter++<n){
        d_recursive(arr,k,n,1,0,arr[counter],&sbc);
    }
    return sbc;
}
void d_recursive(int *arr, int k, int n, int p, int prvc, int currc, int *sbc){
    int counter=0;
    while(counter++<n){
        if(currc^arr[counter]*p!=prvc&&arr[counter]*p<k){
            *sbc++;
            d_recursive(arr,k,n,arr[counter]*p,currc,currc^arr[counter]*p,sbc);
        }
    }
}
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    if(argc<3){
        printf("Usage: %s [array of numbers] [value of k]\n",argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    puts("Converting string arguments to integers(and adding them to a set).");
    int i_arr[argc-2];
    int prev_cache=0;
    int curr_cache=atoi(argv[1]);
    int counter=2;
    while(counter++<argc-1){
        if(curr_cache^atoi(argv[counter])!=prev_cache){
            i_arr[counter]=atoi(argv[counter]);
            prev_cache=curr_cache;
            curr_cache^=i_arr[counter];
        }
    }
    puts("Finished conversion.");
    puts("Passing values to function.");
    int output=driver(i_arr,atoi(argv[argc-1]),argc-2);
    printf("Finished. Output is %d.",output);
    return 0;
}
```

I tried printing a character every time d_recursive is called. It was called many times. The weird thing is, it takes the same time to segfault when input array size is 3 and 7. Why?

Comment: "the k subarray product problem". What is that, exactly?

Comment: @user3386109 You are given an array of integers and a constant k. Now find the number of subarrays whose product is less than k

Comment: Seems like a simple sliding window would solve the problem. (I'm assuming that "subarray" implies "contiguous".)

Comment: @user3386109 yeah I know but what's wrong with this code?